# Scroll Effect of another site

Tags: html, css, background, scroll

At first I apologize for my English.
Well, thats the deal
http://www.dotazoneapp.com/site/pt/

this site have a somekind of interesting scroll, when scroll down, the background-image is change his position, with the background-position (I check this on the source). But I don't even know HOW I CAN DO THIS, if is with Jquery or the own CSS. Well, please help me how do that effect

And...

[image]

This button have a animation too scrolling up, it acelerate and not automatic to the top like the reference using id `<a href="#example"> Example2 </a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this (fantastically) easy guide on creating parallax effect using only CSS and without JQuery or any kind of Javascript, which can decrease performance, conflict with other plugins and plenty else.

http://davidwalsh.name/parallax

Comment: Thank you, and I don't understand the [class*="bg__"]. Doesn't work in here, well, maybe Im doing wrong, idk

Comment: This answer is a very cool way to do it - great link. However, I will say, the background remains fixed with this technique. The dotazoneapp site features a slightly slower scroll on the background elements, which you cannot do with pure CSS.

Comment: @RichardLopes ``[class*=]`` is a wildcard attribute selector. It basically says, "Apply these styles to any class name that contains the following".

In this case, ``[class*=bg___]`` is targetting all of those elements in his demo code that start with bg___

Comment: @tigeruppercut, granted that's true and you can do many more wonderful and exciting things with parallax, but I think this is a easy way for the OP to build his first parallax scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the cool parallax scrolling- Checked out the site on chrome dev tools and it looks like they're including this scipt: jquery.parallax-1.1.3. Don't know much about it but looks cool. Investigate here:

http://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/